# Difference in space used

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datafile, windows-server

When reviewing the space used by datafiles in SQL Server, there is a large difference betweens what SQL reports and Windows.

How can this be explained?

[image: SQL]
[image: Windows]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No different.

Space Reserved for your MDF file: 100.21 GB, which is equal to 105,082,944 KB (105,082,944 / 1024 / 1024 = 100.21)

Space Reserved for *_1.ndf: 148.62 GB, which is equal to 155,843,968 KB (155,843,968 / 1024 / 1024 = 148.62)

The numbers match up just fine.  The Operation System is going to see ***Space Reserved***, and that's how you would need to make your comparison.

Space used is going to be how much space is **used** within the database file, but Windows doesn't know or care about that.  The allocation and space **reserved** is the significant part reported by SQL Server which is what represents the footprint on the file system.

Comment: Off course... Mondays...